# PHP arrays: How to sum only the values that the user selected using an html form?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

How may I use the value that the user selected in the html form, when each value is inside an array?

Example:

**HTML Form:**

```
Pick a color!
<input type ="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red">Red<br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue">Blue<br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow">Yellow<br>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$color = array (
 'red' => 10,
 'blue' => 20,
 'yellow' => 30,
);
```

How to get only the values that the user selected and sum them up?
So if the user checked Red and yellow, the result is 40, if the user picked only the blue the result is 20, etc.

Comment: With a `foreach` over the input `$_REQUEST["color"]` array. Then look up the numbers from your `$color` list and add to a sum variable.

Comment: I don´t know who downvoted, or voted to close the question, but I think it´s a valid one, and a good one too. If those tools are there to improve quality, they are of no use at all if people doesn´t explain why they downvoted or voted to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since SO derails into a code-writing service anyway:

```
$sum = array_sum(
     array_intersect_key($color, array_flip($_REQUEST["color"]))
);
```

The [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) part copies whatever your `$color` array contained, after comparing its keys against the input `color[]` list.

Comment: why complicate, is no better what @jcfb say in his answer and use array_sum

Comment: True, skipping the middleman is also a good idea; here those numbers likely don't expose any internal ids.

Comment: How do you know what function to use? I´m just learning php, and the most difficult part for me is to realize where to look for when I do have a problem.

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda Here the grouped function lists provide a bit guidance http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php; you still need to guess what feature might be useful for which situation. And obviously some longer practice or experience is necessary to discover the easiest solution. But the manual often also contains some ready-to-use examples in the comment sections (beware though; some are of varying quality).

Comment: Thanks Mario! Yes, it´s a bit complicated at first... :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you calculating this sum when your form is submitted? If so, something like this:

```
<?php

$colors = array (
    'red' => 10,
    'blue' => 20,
    'yellow' => 30,
);

$total = 0;

if(isset($_POST)) {

    foreach($_POST['color'] as $color) {

        if(array_key_exists($color, $colors))
            $total += $colors[$color];

    }

}

// tick red, total is 10
// tick red and blue, total is 30
// tick red and yellow, total is 40
// etc...

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

why you dont simply put "actual value" on value attribute??
like :

```
 Pick a color!
 <input type ="checkbox" name="color[]" value="10">Red<br>
 <input type ="checkbox" name="color[]" value="20">Blue<br>
 <input type ="checkbox" name="color[]" value="30">Yellow<br>
```

and then loop for sum it up!!